# Bootstrap 4 - Vertically Centering List Items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a web page that uses the Bootstrap 4 beta. In this page, I have an inline list. I want the content of each list item to be vertically centered so the items line up. As shown in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/od2qnkLIkQ), they're currently off-center. I'm using the following code:

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center align-items-center">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><h2>Hello</h2></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Help</button></li>
</ul>
```

My question is, how do I get the list items to be vertically centered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though flexbox hasn't been applied

Try this:

```
.align-items-center {
    -ms-flex-align: center!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Bootply Demo](https://www.bootply.com/i0qQA1PTv3)

Note: there is no CSS method of vertically aligning the contents of elements that *do not share a parent* with each other. The above aligns the `li`...not their contents..but seems to have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, I duplicated those list-items, changed one h2 to an h1, and the other from h2 to an h6. Any idea why just the h6 looks slightly off-center? https://www.bootply.com/16F7svEvwD

Answer (score 6):

Use the included flexbox utils (no extra CSS is needed)..

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><h2>Hello</h2></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Help</button></li>
</ul>
```

https://www.bootply.com/NLcGDLFEjJ

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Just add the bootstrap class `align-middle` to both the `<li>` tags.

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center align-items-center">
  <li class="list-inline-item align-middle"><h2>Hello</h2></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item align-middle"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Help</button></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps. You can check the result [here](https://www.bootply.com/hSIuAarjkp).

Answer (score 0):

For me using d-flex in the li element and adding my-auto class to the  element worked

```
<li class="d-flex"><a class="my-auto" href="#">Some Title Here</a></li>
```