# Bootstrap 4 - Vertical Align List Item Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 4. In this app, I have an inline list. I need to vertically centre the content of each list item. At this time, the content of each item is vertically centred on the top as shown in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/gxhpfIyeiw). The relevant code looks like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline" style="text-align: center;">
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <div class="list-option">Football</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <div class="list-option">Baseball</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <div class="list-option">Basketball</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <div class="list-option">Golf</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <div class="list-option">Hockey</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I posted a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881450/bootstrap-4-vertically-centering-list-items). However, in that question, I wasn't specific enough. The answerers did answer the question though. For that reason, I wanted to ensure they got credit and opened a new question. This question is really about vertically centring the *content* within each item. How do I do this in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: why don't you provide a ```top-margin```?

Comment: add this to your ```list-option``` class to center it : ```padding-top: 1.4rem;```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

to `.list-option`

[bootply](https://www.bootply.com/m5EFQcyohi)